# Lagrangian for Perfect fluid Stress-Energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The wiki article on the Einstein-Hilbert action for General Relativity [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action#Derivation_of_Einstein.27s_field_equations) that the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ is related to the Lagrangian of matter, $\mathcal{L}_M$, by
$$T_{\mu\nu}=-2\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_M}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}+g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_M.$$
In FRW cosmology, in the comoving frame, the stress-energy tensor $T^\mu{}_\nu$ for a perfect fluid is given by
$$T^\mu{}_\nu={\rm diag}(-\rho,p,p,p)$$
with equation of state
$$p=w\ \rho$$
and
$$\rho \propto a^{-3(1+w)},$$
where $w$ is a constant.

What is the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_M$ that leads to the FRW perfect fluid stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Searching for "general relativity perfect fluid lagrangian" with the search engine of your choosing should point you towards this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2754v1. The authors use matter current conservation to derive the fagrangian of an ideal fluid from the standart definition you gave. There are some  non-obvious steps involved but they are referenced. They also give some explicit expressions for simple EoS: The $P=\omega \rho$ case is included.

Comment: Section II of this preprint may be  helpful. https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00607v2

Comment: The lagrangian is fully discussed here, equations 8 9 10 https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03140

Answer (score 0):

An action principle for general relativistic perfect fluids is given in Section 5 of

Marsden, J. E., Montgomery, R., Morrison, P. J., & Thompson, W. B. (1986). [Covariant Poisson brackets for classical fields. Annals of Physics](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/1986/07-MaMoMoTh1986/MaMoMoTh1986.pdf), 169(1), 29-47.