# Stress energy tensor from equations of motion

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In field theory, if you are given an action $S$, the standard way to find the stress energy tensor is 
$$ T^{\mu\nu}= -\frac{2}{\sqrt g}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}.$$
But there are many examples of classical equations of motion that cannot be derived from an action (take first order hydrodynamics as an example). My question is: If you only know the equations of motion of a system (and no corresponding action exists), how do you find the stress energy tensor?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308613/2451

Comment: See the rayleigh-plessot equation.